# c# prevent datagridview from loading

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is populated when the form loads like this:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

bindingSource.DataSource = //some list returned from database;

dgv.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

If there is a case where there are millions of records that would cause the grid to load slowly, then I'd like to have a button somewhere on the form that the user could click to stop the grid from being populated. I don't know if this is reasonable.

I'm open to any feedback - including being told the design is bad.

EDIT: please explain the -1. I asked a question that I didn't see the answer to and included code. Trying to figure out the correct protocol here.

Comment: You're asking a computer to do 2 different tasks simultaniously. Usually when loading, it'll only go through the lines of code that'll load the information. it won't run through other button methods because the code won't reach that point. So I doubt myself if that's manageable and efficient. But If it's possible, then it should manage that during the event of reaching the database at the same time.

Comment: Try implementing it using [Task Cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data in the DataGridView row by row and check if the button has been pressed each time a new row is going to be added. That would make populating the DataGridView slightly slower, but does provide the functionality you're asking for...

Maybe set a bool to true if the button has been pressed. Then check bool-status in the population loop and if true use 'return;' to exit the populationloop.